# Using Celery + SQS with Django - Celery not respecting broker_transport_options

Tags: python, celery, amazon-sqs, django-celery

I'm trying to set up a celery worker with AWS SQS as the message broker. However, celery does not use the queue I have defined, nor does it even use the correct region. It instead creates a us-east-1 queue instead of using the ap-southeast-2 ones.

I have set up a custom queue in the ap-southeast-1 region, and added it to the Celery configs as below:

```
app = Celery("celery")
CELERY_CONFIG = {
    "task_serializer": "json",
    "accept_content": ["json"],
    "result_serializer": "json",
    "result_backend": None,
    "worker_enable_remote_control": False,
    "task_acks_late": True,
    "worker_prefetch_multiplier": 1,
    "broker_url": broker_url,
    "task_default_queue": "scraperQueue",
    "broker_transport": "sqs",
    "broker_transport_options ": {
            "region": "ap-southeast-2",
            "visibility_timeout": 700,
            "polling_interval": 5,
            'queue_name_prefix': 'celery',
            'predefined_queues': {
                    'scraperQueue': {
                        'url': os.environ.get('SQS_URL'),
                        'access_key_id': os.environ.get('SQS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'),
                        'secret_access_key': os.environ.get('SQS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY'),
                    }
                }
            },
}
app.conf.update(**CELERY_CONFIG)
app.autodiscover_tasks()
```

The script I use to start the worker is as follows:
`celery -A celery_file worker --loglevel=INFO --concurrency=1 -P solo --logfile=/var/log/celery.log --without-gossip --without-mingle --without-heartbeat -O fair`

However, when I check the scraperQueue I created in the AWS SQS Console, I see that no messages are sent. However, if I switch the AWS region to us-east-1, I see that a new Queue called scraperQueue has been created and is being used to send the messages.

I've tried changing/removing the task_default_queue setting, changing the region and creating/deleting existing queues, but nothing seems to work. How do I get celery to use the queue I have defined, or at the very least, how do I get it to create its queue in ap-southeast-2 instead of us-east-1 (which I understand is the default)?

Comment: I finally managed to fix it myself. For some reason, the celery configs defined here were not being used by the Celery+Django combination. I had to redefine all these in the Django settings.py file and it worked flawlessly.